# Showing mysql entries in a php table as a restaurant menu with pictures

Tags: php, datatables

Normally we see php tables in rows with data spread across the columns as shown below;

```
<?php
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM cat WHERE cidc='$company_id' AND status=1 ORDER BY 
id desc";
$result_set=mysql_query($sql_query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
{
?>

  <tr>
  <td valign="top" ><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
  <td align="left" valign="top" ><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
  <td align="middle" valign="top"><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
  <td align="left" valign="top" ><?php echo $row[2]; ?><br><span 
  class="custom-select-sm"><?php echo $row[5]; ?></span></td>
  <td align="right" >
      <?php if($uaccess == 'Admin') { ?>
      <a href="javascript:edt_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')"><img 
   src="../images/edit1.png" width="20" height="20" title="Edit" /> 
  </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:hide_id('<?php echo $row[0]; ?>')"> 
  <img src="../images/hide.png" width="20" height="20" title="Archive"/></a>
      <?php }  ?>
   </td>
   </tr>
```

I want every single cell of my table (say has 4 columns and 4 rows) to show all data within a single cell corresponding to a single ID, such as...

```
  <tr>
  <td valign="top" ><?php echo $row[0]; ?><br><?php echo $row[1]; ?><br> 
  </td><?php echo $row[2]; ?>>br><?php echo $row[3]; ?>
  <td valign="top" ><?php echo $row[0]; ?><br><?php echo $row[1]; ?><br> 
  </td><?php echo $row[2]; ?>>br><?php echo $row[3]; ?>
  <td valign="top" ><?php echo $row[0]; ?><br><?php echo $row[1]; ?><br> 
   </td><?php echo $row[2]; ?>>br><?php echo $row[3]; ?>
  <td valign="top" ><?php echo $row[0]; ?><br><?php echo $row[1]; ?><br> 
 </td><?php echo $row[2]; ?>>br><?php echo $row[3]; ?>
  </tr>
```

How do i write the code/ query etc etc

Comment: Doing some research it shows that I need a PHP dynamic grid output

Comment: <?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cat ORDER BY catname"); 
$i = 0;
$dyn_table = '<table border="1" cellpadding="10" align="center">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    $id = $row["id"];
    $cat_n = $row["catname"];
 $cat_d = $row["catdesc"];
 $img = $row["catimg"];  
    if ($i % 3 == 0) { 
        $dyn_table .= '<tr><td valign="top">' . $id .'<br>'. $img .'<br>'. $cat_n .'<br>'. $cat_d . '</td>';
    } else {
        $dyn_table .= '<td valign="top">' . $id .'<br>'. $img .'<br>'. $cat_ .'<br>'. $cat_d . '</td>';
    }     $i++; }
$dyn_table .= '</tr></table>'; ?>